# OneDrive sync precedence: seldom asked

Tags: sync, onedrive

OneDrive sync is two-way, so deleting a file in the folder deletes it on the website and vice versa.

How does it know which of the two should be used as the reference?

E.g.

I add item A on OneDrive website.

Then add item B to a local folder (was offline) and sync the folder to the cloud.

How does OneDrive know to add A then B instead of deleting A and only adding B (taking reference from my local folder)?

Also, if I have a new device and would like it to sync to OneDrive cloud, what prevents OneDrive from thinking that the empty folder in my new device is what I want in my cloud, since the sync is two-way?

Comment: I am confused by the question.  If you delete a folder or file on a system with OneDrive synchronized with your account, the action of you deleting the folder or file itself will initiate the synchronization update.

Comment: @Ramhound I should have been more specific, I meant that the local folder was originally synced, then taken offline, then item B was added while offline, and then it was forced to sync. For instance, Linux OneDrive works like this.

Comment: this question does not make any sense. obviously an event triggers the sync. if you add a drive that contains data, then it will be synced to the cloud rather than the added drive being wiped of course.

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, the state (including history most probably) of the remote and the local data is saved on each operation. When you sync, a diff of states is created between the local and remote. Then the operations are performed based on that.